# Passing Parameter to Inline Function for Top Level CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I need to pass parameter to inline function for the top level CTE. Is it possible to do that?

Here is something what i need.

```
with a
(
 select * from table1
),
b as
(
   select * from
   (
      select * from inline_function(a.parameter1)
   )
   as c
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to call the function once for each row returned by the CTE `a`.

To do that you should use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
with a
(
  select *
  from dbo.table1
),
b as
(
  select c.*
  from a
    cross apply dbo.inline_function(a.parameter1) as c
)
```